# "You" have nothing to do with "it" vs "it" has nothing to do with "you"

Tags: pronouns, auxiliary-verbs, negation

To me, it sounds no different at all but I'm not sure of it. Do they have the same meaning?

> 1. ***You*** have nothing to do with ***it***.   OR ***It*** has nothing to do with ***you***.
> 2. ***4am*** has nothing to do with **your *English level***. OR **Your English level** has nothing to do with ***4am***.

For second example, I told one of my friend who read the reading practice at 4am as she was awoken and said "Tired 4am voice". I always adore her accent and pronunciation.

I have no idea how to provide my research for this kinda question.
Thanks.

Comment: In the second example, you need to replace "is" with "has"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression *X has nothing to do with Y* can mean two things (at least):

1. If Y is the word "you," it can mean **X does not concern you**. When used in this way, the expression can be used in a somewhat unmannerly way, as if to say, "X is none of your business!"

> **Ted**: I think maybe you're spending too much money this Christmas.
>   **Ed**: What I put in my shopping cart has nothing to do with you.

2. It can also mean **X is not the cause of Y**. In the following dialogue, assume Ned is a salesman who had no sales last month:

> **Ned**: Our team won Team of the Month. We should go celebrate!
>   **Ed**: Ned, you had nothing to do with this award.

(That could be regarded as a harsh remark, but the phrase can also be used in a reassuring way, to say that something is not your fault:)

> **Jed**: What a calamity! I feel so bad that this happened.
>   **Ed**: Don't fret about it, Jed. You had nothing to do with this.

Back to what you were trying to say:

> *4am has nothing to do with your English.*

I guess I can sort of see how this might mean *the time of day doesn't affect your English*, but I'd probably not word it that way. Instead, I'd say something more along the lines of:

> ***Your English is great, even at 4am.***

As for the other way around:

> *Your English has nothing to do with 4am.*

That one seems a bit harder to catch the meaning. I might word that like this:

> ***Your English isn't affected by the time of day.***
>   ***Your English is good [round the clock](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/round-around-the-clock).***

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!! But you didn't seem to answer my question whether X and Y are interchangeable with the same meaning?

Comment: @puputeh24 - I wouldn't go so far as to say they are "interchangeable," although I think the two expressions would be similar and related. I think it also depends on what X and Y are.